# Did new copied files break the import rules?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I created a django project using django 1.4.2. There is one 'app'(`adsite`) in this project. And It works. But when I copied some 'py' files into the 'app' folder, I got `No module named models` error in views.py . and `Parent module adsite.adsiteviews.mainhanlder does not exist.` Should I register the new files to `__init__` in the 'app'? Did new coped files break the `import` rules?

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader    
from adsite.models import UserInfo

def showusers(request):
    userlist = UserInfo.objects.all()
    c = Context({
        'userlist':userlist,
    })
    t = loader.get_template('users.html')

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

copied file:
adsiteviews.py

```
class mainhanlder(TemplateView)
    def get(self):
    """ """        
    variables = {
                'user': self.get_current_user(),
                'mchosts' : MCHOSTS, 
                'servers' : servers}

    index_templ = tmpl_lookup.get_template("index.html")
    body = index_templ.render(**variables)
    self.write(body)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'adsite.adsiteviews.mainhandler.as_View()'),
    url(r'^users/$', 'adsite.views.showusers'),
```

I have no clues about this problem. any suggestions would be appreciated. thx for your time.

Comment: adsiteviews.py is modified from application which developed using tornado. Now I want to modified it to use django, maybe class based view in django.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your urlconf is completely wrong; you can't call the class-based views the same way you do with the function-based ones. Specifically, your urls.py should look like this:

```
from adsite.adsiteviews import mainhandler

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', mainhandler.as_View()),
    url(r'^users/$', 'adsite.views.showusers'),
```

Second, the error `No module named models` probably means exactly that: you need to have file named models.py in your `adsite` dir, and it should contain a `UserInfo` model definition. I'm not sure how come you don't have the models.py since it's usually created by the commant `startapp` by default.